# What does this icon mean in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of clans, while viewing members in my clan, sometimes there is an icon to the right of the name that displays a person behind a person.  What does that icon mean?

Answer (score 4):

Based on my observations, I think its to show who you have added as a friend within the game. If you look at your Social tab, you will see all you have added as a friend. Those names should match the ones with that icon in your clan.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgbmT.jpg) to see screenshots. (They were too large to put directly into the post)